# Showing that graph of spanning trees are connected

Tags: graphs, spanning-trees

Suppose we have a graph $H$, where each vertex represents a spanning tree of another graph $G$.

We create an edge between 2 vertices in $H$ if $ST_1$ (spanning tree) contains exactly one edge not in $ST_2$ (and vice versa).

How do we show that $H$ is connected?

Answer (score 1):

Use induction on the number of edges and vertices in $G$.  Fix some edge $e$ of $G$.  If $S$ and $T$ are two different spanning trees that do not use $e$, apply the induction hypothesis on the graph $G\setminus e$.  If both use $e$, apply the inductive hypothesis to the contracted graph $G/e$.  If only one does, w.l.o.g., $S$, replace $T$ by $T'$, obtained by adding $e$ to $T$ and removing any edge in the (unique) cycle in $T+e$.  Either $T'$ is $S$, or we are back in a previous case.

Answer (score 0):

So two vertices in $H$ are connected by an edge if their corresponding spanning trees $ST_1$ and $ST_2$ differ in exactly two edges $e \in ST_1$ and $e' \in ST_2$, or equivalently, if by removing $e$ from $ST_1$ and adding $e'$ to it, we get $ST_2$.

Therefore, a path in $H$ corresponds to a sequence of these remove and add operations. You need to show that for any two spanning trees $ST_i$ and $ST_j$, with any number of different edges you can obtain $ST_j$ by applying these operations iteratively to $ST_i$. More specifically, you need to prove that for any edge that is present only in $ST_i$, if we remove that edge, there is another edge only present in $ST_j$ that we can add to $ST_i$ such that it remains a tree.